# JS Error with Ajax: TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null (not a duplicate, none of the other answers worked)

Tags: javascript, ajax, innerhtml

When my code runs and is supposed to edit a DOM element in an Ajax onload, it doesn't work and gives me an error: TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null.

I have checked pretty much everything and I do believe I haven't made a mistake with class names or anything.

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Ajax Crash Course</title>
</head>
<body>
     <button class="userBtn">Click for User</button>

    <br>
    <br>

    <div class="DOMInsertions"></div>

    <script src="ajax2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
const userBtn = document.querySelector('.userBtn');
let listNum = 0;


userBtn.addEventListener('click', userCall);

function userCall() {

    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;

    xhr.open('GET', 'user.json', true);

    xhr.onload = function() {
        if( xhr.status === 200 ){
            let user = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            let { name, id, email } = user;

            let className = `userList_${listNum}`;

            textToDOM('h1', 'User:', 'heading');

            textToDOM('ul', 'Yo', className)

            let list = document.querySelector(className)

            list.innerHTML = `
            <li>ID: ${id} </li>
            <li>Name: ${name} </li>
            <li>Email: ${email}</li>
            `
            listNum++;
        }
    }

    xhr.send();
}
```

Comment: textToDOM() is defined elsewhere and I have checked in the dev tools, it does insert the element and have the correct class.

Comment: Can you check if your "list" is null and work backwards? I have a feeling that the DOM is not ready immediately after the textToDOM call.

Comment: @Schien It was null, but I can't seem to find a way to have it not be null. Whether that be not using a variable and directly saying it or even using a timeout on it.

Comment: Can you share the code for textToDOM?

Comment: @Schien
```
function textToDOM(elType, text, className) {
    addition = document.createElement(elType);

    Node = document.createTextNode(text);

    addition.appendChild(Node)
    DOMInsert.appendChild(addition)

    addition.classList.add(className)
}
```

Comment: DOMInsert is a variable for a query selector to a div just above the script tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I have actually rebuilt the script and found a few issues:

DOMInsert is not well defined. You can fix this by adding an ID to your injection container and refer to it by the ID:

```
<div class="DOMInsertions" id="dominsert"></div>
```

Then use this:

```
document.getElementById('dominsert').appendChild(addition);
```

The second problem is that your className is nowhere defined. As a result, your "list" is undefined.

Comment: That seemed to work, but I have a new issue. If I add more than one, it doesn't work, because it seems like a unique className isn't being applied. the variable for the number is incrementing properly but it doesn't seem to work when it goes over textToDOM() again.